# Search 2-dimensional Array for Person's name and Average that Person's Numerical Data Java

Tags: java, arrays, database, search, multidimensional-array

I have a database meant for student names and grades. The data is stored in a two dimensional array of objects.(This is a requirement) Each student has its own row, in which 5 pieces of data are stored, the first column contains the person's name and the next 4 columns contain that persons 4 different test scores. The user can input and add data. I am able to add and display the data fine, but what I am having trouble with is calculating averages.

The user should be able to enter a name and search through the database to see if that person exists in it. If that person is in the database I have to display that person's test average. This should all happen when my studentAverage button is pressed. I can't figure out how to search for the person and after that how to calculate their average, can someone help me out with that?

I am assuming that I have to use a Object type two-dimensional array because both strings and double values have to go into it.

```
public class StudentGrades extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    final int STUDENTS = 14;
    final int GRADES = 4;
    Object[][] database = new Object[STUDENTS][GRADES + 1];
    int studentCount = 0;
```

...

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    //declare variables
    double grade1 = Double.parseDouble(test1.getText());
    double grade2 = Double.parseDouble(test2.getText());
    double grade3 = Double.parseDouble(test3.getText());
    double grade4 = Double.parseDouble(test4.getText());
    String name = firstInput.getText() + " " + lastInput.getText() + ":";

    if (grade1 >= 0 & grade1 <= 100 & grade2 >= 0 & grade2 <= 100 & grade3 >= 0 & grade3 <= 100 & grade4 >= 0 & grade4 <= 100){           
        //add data
        database[studentCount][0] = name;
        database[studentCount][1] = grade1; 
        database[studentCount][2] = grade2;
        database[studentCount][3] = grade3;
        database[studentCount][4] = grade4;

        //add to student count
        studentCount = studentCount + 1;

        //limit number of students
        if (studentCount == 15){
            addButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }  
    else {
        errorLabel.setText("Please Enter Valid Data.");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Wow... whoever gave you this "requirement" to use an `Object[][]` for a "database" is not competent to teach Java, or programming in general.  You have my sympathy.

Comment: *I mean it had to be a two dimensional array, not specifically a Object one, I was just told that it would work best when working with different data types...

Comment: Starting off by treating Java as if it were Basic (from the 1960s) is never a good idea.  Ideally you should have a `Student` class that stores the name and a `List<Double>` for the grades, and then have a `Map<String,Student>` where the key is the name.  Then the `Student` object would have an `average()` method that would calculate and return the average.  But you probably haven't learned about classes yet.

Comment: You should almost always use the short-circuiting logical AND operator `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement of using `Object[][]` as the database really impedes clear programming. It's not an *object-oriented* approach at all. (Are you sure you're not supposed to use a one-dimensional array of student objects?)

But, given the two-dimensional `Object` array that you are using, you search for a given student name by comparing it to each `database[i][0]` column, casting each one to type `String` first, and looping through the entire array until you find a matching name.

To calculate the average grade for the student at `database[i]`, you simply add the other columns together, casting each one to `double`, then divide by the number of grades.

Using an `Object` type to store both names and numbers forces you to cast them back into their original types before you can do any operations (comparison and arithmetic) on them.